# How to fill between back of countertop and the wall

Tags: hole, countertops, gap

This is a section of countertop around the sink in the bathroom of my house.

Whoever installed it left a pretty large gap between the back of the counter and the wall. Its filled with silicone. The silicone now looks untidy and is impossible to paint over. the gap is about 0.75cm (image below)

I want to fix this so i can paint easily down to the counter, but without replacing the countertop.
I would appreciate some advice on my options.

I am thinking

- Caulk. it may be a bit wide for caulk though.
- filler. just pollyfilla and try to get a reasonable finish.

thank you for any advice.

[image]

Comment: Does the drywall stop short of the counter top, or does the counter top not go all the way back to the drywall? If it's a drywall issue, that's _reasonably_ easy to fix by redoing the drywall. Of course, that's a _much_ bigger fix than adding some caulk...

Comment: The gap may not be as big as the caulking would suggest.  Remove the old caulking and then you will know how much of a gap you need to deal with.

Answer (score 0):

Depends where you live. Basically you need a paintable tube based sealant/caulk/filler. A flexible one is a must. Regular filler WILL crack.

I'd use Tec7 an MS Polymer, which glues strongly, hardens quickly, does not shrink and remains flexible, overpaintable, resistant to UV rays and very resistant to aging.

I'd look at adding trim options too. Either timber to paint or replicating the counter top and adding a small up stand in the same material etc.

Comment: Not sure UV resistance is critical inside a bathroom (unless OP tans in there, too). Depending on the size of the gap, a backer rod into the gap will reduce the amount of caulk needed and make the job much easier.

Comment: thanks for the replies. 
@Freeman: The issue is the counter is too short and does not meet the drywall.

Comment: @handyman: the trim idea might be a winner, as might the Tec7. UV resistance is nice but not necessary in a windowless downstairs bathroom.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of options come to mind.

Add some kind of trim, as mentioned, but more specifically maybe a ceramic or porcelain tile cove piece. You might also consider a tile backsplash. At .75cm you’d still probably have a bit of a gap but silicone caulk filling a much smaller gap would look fine/normal.

Another option to consider is if you can find that same countertop material (appears to be quartz) you could have a fabricator make a 8-10cm tall backsplash. The trickiest part would be matching the existing material. Not impossible unless it was discontinued. Take a picture of it and head to a slab yard or wherever they sell stone slabs near you.